# QueryTables.Add 1004 issue for pulling from the web

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I keep getting Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error as I'm trying to pull this information from the web through VBA. I'm at my wits end because I can't find any errors that I might have made in this and I'm thinking it some sort of permissions issue. I'm running it on Excel 2016 on Windows. Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub QueryStarter()
Dim url As String
url = "https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2021-01-23"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SFI").Activate
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=Worksheets("SFI").Range("A1")) 'this is where 1004 pops up
    .Name = "My Query"
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = "historicalRateTbl"
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection:= url
```

should be

```
Connection:="URL;" & url
```